# Proj4Leaflet create CRS scales/resolution from WMTS getCapacilities ScaleDenominator

Tags: leaflet, wmts

I trying to set up the CRS scales/resolution for a map accordingly to the provided information of an WMTS getCapabilities request. At the moment I'm playing with the following [service](http://geo.sv.rostock.de/geodienste/stadtplan/service?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities).

The service provides me with the following TileMatrix information:

```
<TileMatrix>
  <ows:Identifier>00</ows:Identifier>
  <ScaleDenominator>1889880.95238</ScaleDenominator>
  <TopLeftCorner>200000.0 6075000.0</TopLeftCorner>
  <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
  <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
  <MatrixWidth>3</MatrixWidth>
  <MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
...
```

Based on an OpenLayers example from [this](http://www.orka-mv.de/nutzung.html) source the resolutions should be:

```
[
   529.166666667,
   ...
]
```

I've created a fiddle that uses the resolutions specified in the example. Using these informations the map displays as expected. But how do I calculate the resolution based on the provided ScaleDenominator?

Comment: fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/undw9p2e/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to calculate the resolutions using the following equation:

**resolution = ScaleDenominator * PixelWidth**

529.166666667 = 1889880.95238 * 0.00028