# Find the right values for bounds and origin for Proj4Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, proj, proj4js, proj4leaflet

I'm using [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) to use tile layers with a different CRS (EPSG:25832) in my leaflet project.

Now I am somehow lost in finding the correct values for the bounds and origin of the tiles I want to use ([https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wmts_topplus_open/tile/1.0.0/web/default/EU_EPSG_25832_TOPPLUS/{z}/{y}/{x}.png](https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wmts_topplus_open/tile/1.0.0/web/default/EU_EPSG_25832_TOPPLUS/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D.png)). I've constructed this tile request by inspecting the capabilities of [this WMTS](https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wmts_topplus_open/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) (here is a [link to the metadata](https://sg.geodatenzentrum.de/web_public/gdz/dokumentation/deu/TopPlusOpen.pdf) of the service).

Thanks to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/153645/157032), I've already figured out how to calculate the values for the resolution.

```js
var epsg25832 = new L.Proj.CRS(
  'EPSG:25832',
  '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs', {
    origin: ? ? ? ,
    bounds: ? ? ? ,
    resolutions: [
      4891.969810252,
      2445.984905126,
      1222.9924525616,
      611.4962262808,
      305.7481131404,
      152.87405657048,
      76.43702828524,
      38.21851414248,
      19.109257071296,
      9.554628535648,
      4.777314267824,
      2.388657133912,
      1.194328566956,
      0.597164283478
    ],
  }
);
```

But I have no clue how to find the right values for bounds and origin. I can only find `<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>` in the capabilities of the WMTS. Does anyone know how to get the right values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An excerpt from your webservice tilematrix `EU_EPSG_25832_TOPPLUS` in https://sgx.geodatenzentrum.de/wmts_topplus_open/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

```
 <TileMatrixSet>
      <ows:Identifier>EU_EPSG_25832_TOPPLUS</ows:Identifier>
      <ows:SupportedCRS>EPSG:25832</ows:SupportedCRS>
      <TileMatrix>
        <ows:Identifier>00</ows:Identifier>
        <ScaleDenominator>17471320.7509</ScaleDenominator>
        <TopLeftCorner>-3803165.98427 8805908.08285</TopLeftCorner>
        <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
        <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
        <MatrixWidth>6</MatrixWidth>
        <MatrixHeight>5</MatrixHeight>
      </TileMatrix>
      ....
```

> 0.00028 = 0.00028m = 0.28mm => explanation at https://enonline.supermap.com/iServer9D/Appendix/scale.htm (if you know better docs, comments welcome)
>
> pixelsize = resolution = 0.00028 * scaledenominator

The origin should be

> TopLeftCorner x and y values in an Javascript array, e.g `[-3803165.98427, 8805908.08285]`

To calculate the bounds, you may look at:

> Formula for bottom right corner X
>
> TopLeftCorner X + MatrixWidth * TileWidth * ScaleDenominator * 0.00028 = 3710899.64428

and

> Formula for bottom right corner Y
>
> TopLeftCorner Y - MatrixHeight * TileWidth * ScaleDenominator * 0.00028 = 2544186.72573

You now have the values to make the bounds as coordinates for top left corner and bottom right corner can help you deduce xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax

According to [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet), bounds should be an [`L.bounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#bounds)

Althought it was a bit annoying to sort out my calculations, I've confirmed them using WMTS with your web service within QGIS and also using [QGIS Network Logger](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgisnetworklogger/) (need QGIS 3.5 or more and it rocks to learn OGC by inspecting network calls although you need to be aware of cache)

Comment: nice tip about the plugin, I always use (perhaps used) something like Fiddler as a proxy and configure the network settings accordingly

Comment: Me too in the old days but not on Windows anymore so this plugin is welcome, for me, at least